# '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file in angular

Tags: angular, build, unrecognized-selector

I am facing issues while i building a angular 2 application, when i run this command to build the production build for angular 2, getting error message

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Here is the package .json code.

```
 {
  "name": "acl-web",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Admin Zone app",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "ngc": "node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "protractor": "protractor",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "serve:upgrade": "http-server",
    "serve:cli": "http-server dist/",
    "serve:aot": "lite-server -c bs-config.aot.json",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080 --config webpack.config.js --content-base src/ --host 0.0.0.0",
    "test:webpack": "karma start karma.webpack.conf.js",
    "build:prod": " ./node_modules/.bin/rimraf dist && node --max-old-space-size=3072 ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --bail --progress",
    "build:babel": "babel src -d src --extensions \".es6\" --source-maps",
    "copy-dist-files": "node ./copy-dist-files.js",
    "i18n": "ng-xi18n",
    "jQuery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.5",
    "@angular/tsc-wrapped": "^0.5.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.4.5",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^3.1.33",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.20",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.5.1",
    "@types/angular": "~1.5.16",
    "@types/angular-animate": "^1.5.5",
    "@types/angular-cookies": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/angular-mocks": "^1.5.5",
    "@types/angular-resource": "^1.5.6",
    "@types/angular-route": "^1.3.2",
    "@types/angular-sanitize": "^1.3.3",
    "@types/core-js": "~0.9.37",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.54",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.55",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.4",
    "babel-cli": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-angular2": "^0.0.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.0.0-beta.5",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.16.1",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "jasmine": "~2.4.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "less": "^2.7.1",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.3",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "ng2-radio-group": "0.0.6",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "primeng": "^1.1.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "rollup": "^0.36.0",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^4.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "source-map-explorer": "^1.3.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-node": "^1.3.0",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "~2.1.5",
    "webpack": "2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.4.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "repository": {},
  "config": {
    "unsafe-perm": true
  }
}
```

Above is my current package.json code

Comment: Can you please mention the exact command you are using for building application?

Comment: " npm run build:prod " this is the command i ran into the terminal.

Comment: Then can you please provide the `script` entered in `package.json` for `build`.
You can find that from the scripts section in `package.json`.
This issue seems like a typo issue.

Comment: @jins I have updated the question and added my current package json code, please check and help.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `package.json` file, there's an unwanted space at the beginning, for the script `build:prod`. Please remove the space and try.

```
"build:prod": "./node_modules/.bin/rimraf dist && node --max-old-space-size=3072 ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --bail --progress",
```

Hope this helps!